# What was behind the quick decision of the two pilots to join the captain in death in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

One says that he will need help to destroy the Engineer ship but both pilots if even one was really required would not be. With almost no deliberation they both decide that death was preferable to joining Vickers.

Was this a bit of dark comedy, showing just what a miserable person Vickers was or was it more reflective of how low her chances of survival were and the two pilots just wanted a quick death rather than one eventually fighting over the limited resources (2 years for one person so less than a year for the three not to mention Shaw) of the escape pod? Based on the distances involved, rescue was impossible even if the company decided to send another ship -- I forget if the time in sleep chambers was mentioned but presumably the trip took many years if such chambers were needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Camaraderie

The pilots simply didn't want to abandon their friend, the captain. They've been through a lot together, and didn't want him to die alone in the end. It was a loyal and loving decision that showed how close they all were.

As far as I understood, it didn't have much to do with them hating Vickers or being afraid of struggling in the escape pod in a few months.

Comment: Well, I can understand loyalty but if I thought I had a chance to return to Earth I would not so quickly choose certain death. Did you find this discussed in a novelization or maybe a video with the writer/director being interviewed?

Comment: No, it is my interpretation, really. I find it a brave gesture, and can relate (in theory, at least!). Let's see if anyone else can present different interpretations